# passing data from Custom UItableViewCell into ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates

Can this be done with the delegate method?

The reason I'm asking is because I have two buttons on the custom table cell. one deletes the cell and the other sends info from the table cell.m class into another view controller. How can I implement this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can setup a delegate relationship between a cell and the view controller, it follows the same structure and approach as a normal delegate relationship:

1. Create a protocol
2. Add a delegate property (`weak`)
3. Set the delegate when the cell is returned for display
4. nil the delegate when the cell is removed from display
5. Implement the delegate method(s) in the view controller

When you specify the delegate protocol methods, pass the pertinent information, something like:

```
- (void)tableCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell didTriggerButton:(UIButton *)sender;
```

with `didTriggerButton` set to an appropriate name for the purpose of the button. In this way the view controller can get the button if required and has access to the cell (so it can easily get the index path associated with it).

Comment: I've implemented what you said above, but these two lines of code is wrong:@interface CheckInCell : UITableViewCell <NotificationsViewControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NotificationsViewController *notificationsViewController;

Comment: compiler error: cannot find protocol declaration for NotificationsViewControllerDelegate but I have it declared in the notificationsviewcontroller.h

Comment: I think I've fixed it. all i had to do was delete the #import because it was in a loop. thanks you!